# Prevent moveable elements changing the screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a moveable text that moves from left to right. But there is a problem: while the text moves to the right, it increases the screen's width. Can someone help me not increase the width, please?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.big').css("left", -2300 + $(window).scrollTop()*1, + "px;")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="heading_des big">MY LATEST WORK</h1>
```

I've tried `$('.big').css("left", -2300 + $(window).scrollTop()*1, + "px;", "max-width:100%;")` already but it doesn't work.

Comment: add overflow-x: hidden or max-width to body tag

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.big').css("left", -300 + $(window).scrollTop() * 1, +"px;")
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.spacer {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.big {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <h1 class="heading_des big">MY LATEST WORK</h1>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```